# After cyrus-sasl build on Linux Python/pip cannot see sasl.h file

Tags: python, pip, sasl

**Note:** I cannot install libsasl2-dev because I do not have admin rights.

I built cyrus-sasl-2.1.26.tar.gz:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/username/sasl
make install
```

Now header files are there:

```
[username@hostnamebin]$ ls ~/bin/include/sasl
hmac-md5.h  md5global.h  md5.h  prop.h  sasl.h  saslplug.h  saslutil.h
```

But pip still errors out:

```
./python -m pip install /tmp/sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz
```

> sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:23: error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory

Is there any way to make Python/pip see my build instead of looking for default header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing compiler/linker flags:

```
CFLAGS=-I"$HOME"/sasl/include LDFLAGS=-L"$HOME"/sasl/lib ./python -m pip install /tmp/sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz
```

Pass the real directories.

Comment: While this might work I'd recommend to be very careful not to run in seg faults due to a shared library mix.